# Redirect output of Import-Module within ScriptBlock of Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

A module I am importing has several Write-Host commands that I wish to suppress (redirect to NULL).

This works great when I run it directly on a machine:

```
Import-Module 'path\to\module\module.ps1' 2>&1 > $null
```

When running the exact same on a remote host using Invoke-Command, the redirect is ignored and all the output from the module shows up:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
  Import-Module 'path\to\module\module.ps1' 2>&1 > $null
}
```

I've tried different ways of re-direct (i.e. `Out-Null`, etc), all with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  `6>> $null` .
so:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
  Import-Module 'path\to\module\module.ps1' 6>> $null
}
```

This is the ["Example 5: Suppress output from Write-Host"](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host?view=powershell-6#examples) provided by Microsoft, modified accordingly to ["about_Operators"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Awesome! This worked to get rid of Write-Host output but now it was showing the output of Get-Module to list all the included commands. But your link "about Operators" provided the final answer:  ` *>> $null ` redirects all output streams. Thank you :-)